# Check that array of tuples (2d array) has at least 1 item in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

I have a simple type check in my Typescript variable declaration that ensures all elements in an array of tuples are of length 2 and are both numbers:

```
const testArea: [number, number][] = [[0, 0], [0, 220000], [220000, 220000], [220000, 0]];
```

This allows me to correctly initialise the variable, however it still allows an empty array:

```
const testArea: [number, number][] = []; // No error
```

I have tried to re-write this as:

```
const testArea: [[number, number]] = [[0, 0], [0, 220000], [220000, 220000], [220000, 0]]; // error: only allows a single tuple in the array
```

but that didn't work for the primary case of many tuples in the array (though it does seem to prevent an empty array from being valid).

How can I check that the outer array contains tuples of type `[number, number]` and also that it contains at least 1 of these tuples?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use small trick with `rest` operator

```js
type Tuple = [number, number]

type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];

type Data = NonEmptyArray<Tuple>

const data: Data = [] // error
const data1: Data = [[]] // error
const data2: Data = [[1]] // error
const data2: Data = [[1,1]] // Ok
```

There are many alternatives to make sure the array is not empty,

here is the other one:

```js
type NonEmptyArray2<T extends unknown[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? never : T
```

You can take a look on @jcalz's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006111/is-it-possible-to-define-a-non-empty-array-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Seemed to work for my issue. What is going on with this though?: `type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]]` most specifically the: `[T, ...T[]]`

Comment: @currenthandle it means that there is a tuple type where first element always exists. For instance `[T]` - means a tuple with one element, `[T, T]` - a tuple with two elements, `[T, ...T[]]` - a tuple with at least one element, but also might be more