# Custom type NonEmptyArray generates implicit type cast

Tags: typescript

Based on the solution of [Is it possible to define a non empty array type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006111/is-it-possible-to-define-a-non-empty-array-type-in-typescript)

In my implementation I got the error message on line 7: "Type 'string | NonEmptyArray' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'NonEmptyArray' is not assignable to type 'string'." How can I fix this implicit type casting/adjustment in the following code?

```
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]]

export class TestClass {
    private _to: NonEmptyArray<string>;
    
    constructor(to: string | NonEmptyArray<string>) {
        this._to = Array.isArray(to) && to.length ? to : [to];
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `&& to.length`

Comment: Yes, you're right! But then I could still insert an empty array (for example with javascript). After compiling typescript to javascript, there isn't a type NonEmptyArray to prevent this lack.

Comment: Maybe it's the completely wrong approach from me.

Comment: Can you explain me, why `&& to.length` result in this issue? In my opinion, this only check if length isn't equal 0.

Comment: Because both an empty array and a string go to `[to]` that's why TS infers `string | NonEmptyArray`

Comment: You should think of something like `if (!Array.isArray(to)) this._to = [to]; else { here you should process both cases: an empty and non-empty arrays}`