# Typescript NonEmpty array interface breaks with array creation

Tags: typescript

I got a couple of ways to define a `NonEmptyArray` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006111/is-it-possible-to-define-a-non-empty-array-type-in-typescript) question. They are mostly working but I get a weird thing when I use it with a code created array:

```js
type NonEmptyArray<T> = T[] & { 0: T };

function myFunction(param: NonEmptyArray<number>){

}

const myArray = [1,2];

myFunction([1,2]); // OK
myFunction(myArray); // ERROR
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwKIFsygIICcsEMQA8AKgHxQC8URA2gLpQBkUA3lAAwBcVUAvgNwBYAFDCAZgFcEAY2ABLRFBQgAYpJnyEACjC48KLvGRpMOfAQTiUAIwhYSASmbDhPZ0KmIAzsEUhseEAooagBGABoAJlpBESElVWk5RE1QyNp7PigAeiyoAHkAaWF4tSStJX98DOzcpAAlOry6tyA)

The error says:

> Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NonEmptyArray'.
> Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]' but required in type '{ 0: number; }'.(2345)

If I define the type *hard*  then the error is gone:

```js
type NonEmptyArray<T> = T[] & { 0: T };

function myFunction(param: NonEmptyArray<number>){

}

const myArray:  number[] & {0: number} = [1, 2];

myFunction([1,2]); // OK
myFunction(myArray); // Also OK
```

I am not sure if this is a bug in the type definition or in typescript or I am not seeing something. Does anyone knows what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```ts
const myArray = [1,2];
```

Typescript infers it as `number[]` -- a mutable array that may or may not have an element. Hence `myArray[0]` may be undefined. Or, what if there function that resets the array to empty.

```ts
type NonEmptyArray<T> = T[] & { 0: T };

function myFunction(param: NonEmptyArray<number>){

}

const myArray = [1,2];

resetMyArrayEmpty(myArray) // <-- we do not know how it alters the array

myFunction([1,2]); // OK
myFunction(myArray); // ERROR
```

Typescript has no way to guarantee that defined array is going to stay immutable, hence the error. You either take the ownership and explicitly say the type is `number[] & {0: number}` or ensure that the array is immutable as described below:

A way to go about it is to take `readonly` array and define the array as using const assertion. Something like this:

```ts
type NonEmptyArray<T> = readonly T[] & { 0: T };

function myFunction(param: NonEmptyArray<number>){

}

const myArray = [1,2] as const;

myFunction([1,2]); // OK
myFunction(myArray); // OK
```

https://tsplay.dev/N7bVrw

Answer (score 1):

When you use assignment, the variable type is **inferred** if it's not defined, meaning

```
const myArray = [1,2];
// myArray is typed as number[] not [1,2]
```

`number[]` as you know is an array of **any** length containing only numbers.This means that the array is not required to have an `element` at index `0`.

As such, `0` as a `property` is unknown in the `number[]` array.

This results in your error being thrown:

```
Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]' but required in type '{ 0: number; }'
```

As you've already noted, this does however work when you **define** the type for `myArray`.

```
const myArray:  number[] & {0: number} = [1, 2];
```

As this obviously matches the type you defined. (`NonEmptyArray`)

Answer (score 1):

The type is inferred as number[], which can be empty:

```
type NonEmptyArray<T extends {}> = T[] & { 0: T };

function myFunction(param: NonEmptyArray<number>) {

}

const myArray = [1, 2];

myArray.pop(); // Empty the array
myArray.pop();

myFunction([1, 2]); // OK
myFunction(myArray); // ERROR, as expected
```

You can fix that by using `as const`:

```
const myConstArray = [1, 2] as const;
myFunction(myConstArray);
```

But then you get an error `The type 'readonly [1, 2]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'number[]'.`, which you can fix with:

```
type NonEmptyArray<T extends {}> = readonly T[] & { 0: T };
```