# How do you denote that a function is not defined for some value(s) when Typescript doesn't allow you to enforce it?

Tags: typescript, types

Say I wanted to implement, with Typescript, a function `mean` that calculates the mean of an array of `number`s.

Since [it is awkward to enforce that an array be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56006703/4155115), how should I communicate to the users of `mean` that it is not defined for empty arrays?

The options I see are:

1. Return `NaN`.

This seems to be the sort of situation that `NaN` is for, but I hate hate hate hunting down the sources of `NaN`s. So little information communicated about what went wrong. Runtime only.

2. Return `undefined` (changing the type to `(nums: number[]) => number | undefined`).

Not great, but seems way better than 1. since the type says that something could go awry. It doesn't say *why* or *how* though.

3. Throw.

Nice, descriptive message about what went wrong. Couples the caller to the implementation.

4. Return `undefined` and log an error message.

This combines information in the type from 2. with the nice description from 3., but would be really annoying for a caller who didn't mind getting `undefined`s.

Is there a better way than one of these?

Comment: This feels like an opinion question to me.  I don't see how there could be an authoritative/canonical answer.  Could you [edit] it so that there could be fact-based answers?

Answer (score 0):

You should communicate with the users by defining the type correctly so it would be something like:

```
function mean(values: [number, ...number[]]): number
```

I can't see any downside in defining the function like this, or at least fewer downsides than trying to catch the error at runtime.

If you really don't want to do this then you need to decide how the user should behave if they pass in a zero length array.

If it's a catastrophic failure then throw an error. If it is something expected and they need to handle it then change the return type. You've covered most of the possibilities other than returning a tuple. You could return something like

```
type Value = { err: false; value: number } & { err: true; msg: string }
```

which would force the caller to check if there was a problem.

Comment: I agree that catching the error at runtime is not ideal, but [the answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56006703/4155115) makes me think it would be more trouble than it was worth to enforce the non-empty array in the type.
I guess I'm wondering if I can return `undefined` in a way that the user can easily find out why (or something similar).

Comment: The downside of that first function is that it doesn't accept `number[]` which is probably the most common type you would pass into a function like this.

Comment: @AlexWayne Good point, looks like you would need runtime checks in place then unless you are just using object literals.