# Set one or multiple children on React.Children which are required

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have the following code:

```
export interface SectionProps {
  children:
    | React.ReactElement<ListProps | ButtonProps | CardsProps | PillsProps | HeaderProps>
    | React.ReactElement<ListProps | ButtonProps | CardsProps | PillsProps | HeaderProps>[];
}

export const Section = ({ children }: SectionProps) => {
  return <section className="flex flex-col justify-start items-start gap-7 w-full">{children}</section>;
};
```

it should accept a structure like this:

```
      <Section>
        <Header
          title="Recent Blogs"
          icon="BookOpenIcon"
          actions={
            <Actions>
              <Action.Link url="https://google.com" text="DEV.to" />
            </Actions>
          }
        />
        <List>
          {blogPosts.map((post) => (
            <List.Item
              type={post.type}
              title={post.title}
              additional={post.additional}
              subtitle={post.subtitle}
              actions={<Action.Link url="https://google.com" text="Read article" />}
            />
          ))}
        </List>
      </Section>
```

and display a warning in this case below, to provide an Element of the types provided – but it doesn't display a warning/error and compiles without problems.

```
      <Section>
      </Section>
```

How can my type be improved to display a warning when no children is provided?

I think it has something to do with the element array beeing null is okay, but how do I specify that the array is not null?

For a first step, I did this:

```
type NonEmptyArr<T> = [T, ...T[]];
type SectionElement = React.ReactElement<ListProps | ButtonProps | CardsProps | PillsProps | HeaderProps>;
type SectionChildren = NonEmptyArr<SectionElement>;

export interface SectionProps {
  children: SectionElement | SectionChildren;
}
```

but is this the correct way to do this?
The warning now only says please provide a children but not of which possible types.

Comment: You can force the component to accept exactly two children that are JSX elements: `const Section = ({children}: {children: [JSX.Element, JSX.Element]}) => ...`. However you cannot enforce what elements exactly are passed. Even though `React.createElement` function technically returns an instance `ReactElement` which has information about its props, when you instantiate the element using JSX syntax, the type of the expression will be just `JSX.Element` with no information about props. So you cannot enforce only certain jsx element to be passed and this is by design

Comment: Relevant [documentation page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-jsx-result-type)

Comment: I suppose `<Section></Section>` passes an empty array as children, which would be accepted. (`<Section />`, on the other hand, should be rejected?). You can declare a [non-empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56006111/1048572) though

Comment: Hey, I updated my description. What do you think?