# Writing interface for infinite nesting with either or properties

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write an interface for the following type of object.

```json
"Condition": {
  "And": {
    "Or": {
      "userData": [
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "age": "65",
        },
        {
          "name": "Peter",
          "age": "34",
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  "Or" : {
    "userData": [
      {
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": "65",
      },
      {
        "name": "Peter",
        "age": "34",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

The way this datatype is restricted is, that under `Condition` it has to have `And | Or` and inside that `And | Or` it can either have one more `And | Or` or `userData: UserType[]`.

I was trying something but am completely lost on how to write an interface :

[Link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5&ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwPYBVwQPKQE4ENhLYCCYAllALxQDkRcAJtVAD40bbUDcAUN6XMAjYEuAMbQAwkgalgpafEHCx0AN7coUANoBrCCABcsRKnRYh%20QiVIBdI1Jn050tJB4BfHr26hIUB-Sy8nAA6rIAFnT07JRQ6pq6%20lD8xsiumDiWxGR2-tKBznCKQiLiHrz8SqXQAOLYSACuYGHA4fBp6HEa-gA2uADO-aQIpKL4wQBKDT0QRv3A2PwA5lo2Hl6VJSpQdY3NEQDKDQBGS-VNXZoJeoapppDmeATZtvb5QQoCW%20Lcnry%20kneTmC6ViuyaLXCR1O5zALB2sMh7XuEC83BmwCgYFwIB6SFw9DeMkKxWU4li8SuAQ%20cCMlKuV1oDGodPcABpupp3L8vEA) | Typescript Version Used: **4.1.5**

Tried Code

```js
type InfoTypeOperatorApi = 'And' | 'Or';

interface ConditionInterface {
  [key: InfoTypeOperatorApi]: CondidtionType;
};



type ConditionWithAndOr = {
  [key in InfoTypeOperatorApi]: ConditionInterface;
}

interface GroupWithInfoType {
  ClassificationRule: string[];
};

interface GroupWithSubgroup {
    [key: InfoTypeOperatorApi]: ConditionInterface
};

type CondidtionType = GroupWithSubgroup | GroupWithInfoType;


let payload: ConditionInterface = {
    Condition: {
        'And': {},
    }
};
```

Any idea how can I write interface for this?

Comment: Yes, it can go until `6` depth;

Comment: Sorry for that, Yes it can go till 6 levels. Also, the last object will always end with `userData` as it cannot have `Or | And` object with no properties inside them.

Comment: I would like the type to prohibit values with more than 6 levels.

Comment: I am trying to create a UI, which can have subgroups inside groups. Now these sub-groups can either have another group inside them or they can have `userData`. Current requirement is to not allow user to go beyond the depth of 6. I can add a condition to hold the nesting below 6. I can also work with no depth restriction in my interface. I believe it's easier to handle that in the code. That's why I didn't add the depth restriction in my original question.

Comment: No depth restriction: [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRPL1m); with depth restriction: [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVrj5N).  Do either of these work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining.  Note how the depth restriction version is more complicated and harder to deal with, so I hope we can not worry about depth for this question.  If neither solution works for you, what am I missing?  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jcalz, the one without depth restriction answers my question. I would be really glad if you could explain `type Condition` in your answer.

Comment: I would be happy to do it but your reply was quick and I'm worried that you'll discover a problem while I work on my answer.  Could you please take some time to thoroughly test the definition against your use cases and make sure that it does meet your needs (or at least any problems you find are ones you can work around yourself)?  If it does, I'll write up an answer with an explanation.  But if it turns out to violate an important requirement you have, please [edit] the question to show a relevant example and let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I rechecked it, and there is one thing that I think needs to be enforced, Is it possible that `userData` has at least one item in it?

Comment: If you think it needs to be enforced in the *type*, then maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo1BeN) will work for you.  But, like depth, this might be more appropriate to deal with at runtime, since `Array<T>` is much more widely used and understood than `[T, ...Array<T>]`.  Which one do you want to see in the answer?

Comment: Makes sense. I think the original answer without depth restriction is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward definition for your type looks like this:

```
interface ConditionHolder {
  Condition: Condition
}

type Condition =
  { And: Condition | UserData } |
  { Or: Condition | UserData };

interface UserData {
  userData: User[]
}

interface User {
  name: string,
  age: string 
}
```

A `ConditionHolder` is your top-level data structure, with a single `Condition` property of type `Condition`.  The main recursive definition is `Condition`, a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `{And: X}` and `{Or: X}` where `X` is itself a union of `UserData` and `Condition`. (If you want, you could actually give `X` a type name and expand out the definition, but I just left it inline.)  The base case of the recursion is `UserData`, an object type with a `userData` property holding an array of `User` objects.

Hopefully most of that is self-explanatory.  The only point which might seem strange is that `Condition` is a union like `{And: X} | {Or: X}`.  We can't use a more straightforward type with optional properties like `{And?: X, Or?: X}`, since that type allows empty objects `{}`, and you want to require at least `And` or `Or`.  And we don't need to specify a third union member like `{And: X} | {Or: X} | {And: X, Or: X}` because unions in TypeScript are *inclusive*, so allowing `{And: X, Or: X}` is implied already by the first two union members.  (See [Why does A | B allow a combination of both, and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218) for more information).

Let's make sure it works:

```
let v: ConditionHolder;
v = {
  Condition: {
    And: {
      Or: {
        userData: [
          { name: "Alex", age: "65", },
          { name: "Peter", age: "34", }
        ]
      }
    },
    Or: {
      userData: [
        { name: "Alex", age: "65", },
        { name: "Peter", age: "34", }
      ]
    }
  }
}; // okay

v = { Condition: {} } // error!
v = { Condition: { And: {} } } // error!
v = { Condition: { And: { userData: [] } } } // okay
v = { Condition: { And: { Or: { userData: [] } } } } // okay
```

Looks good.

---

Some notes:

- It is possible to use the type system to require that the `userData` array contain at least one member, via [a tuple type with a rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) like `[User, ...User[]]`.  But this might be more complicated than you want to enforce at compile time, especially because it becomes hard to use such types; see [Is it possible to define a non empty array type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56006111/2887218) for more information.  Enforcing array length concerns at runtime is likely easier.
- It is also possible to use the type system to enforce a maximum recursion depth.  The obvious but tedious way to do this would look like:

  ```
  interface ConditionHolder { Condition: Condition6 }
  type Condition6 = { And: Condition5 | UserData } | { Or: Condition5 | UserData };
  type Condition5 = { And: Condition4 | UserData } | { Or: Condition4 | UserData };
  type Condition4 = { And: Condition3 | UserData } | { Or: Condition3 | UserData };
  type Condition3 = { And: Condition2 | UserData } | { Or: Condition2 | UserData };
  type Condition2 = { And: Condition1 | UserData } | { Or: Condition1 | UserData };
  type Condition1 = { And: Condition0 | UserData } | { Or: Condition0 | UserData };
  type Condition0 = { And: UserData } | { Or: UserData };
  ```

  This unrolls the recursion into a fixed structure.  A less obvious approach is to make `Condition` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that is [recursive and conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to count depth:

  ```
  type Condition<D extends any[] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]> =
    D extends [any, ...infer DR] ?
    ({ And: Condition<DR> | UserData } | { Or: Condition<DR> | UserData }) :
    UserData;
  ```

  But either approach is complicated, and it is unlikely to be worth the effort.  Like array length, this might best be enforced only at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQBNhmJgCXQBstpkBvAKGTUxz0wC47td8QqBfKqsATwAOKDG0YhkAXhqVkAQWwtRDDsgA+yAKoBnaABE4YOMi7qZFZAHkoS+u0zqtuqAaMmA3L16hIsRCh19Q2NqWgBXZ1c4FkCoAG0AXW5vcGh4JCdyUOQQOABbCBZtMChQAHMAGhk4MsLkYtKQMuQAehb6kvKAfhz0MBywvIAjaB70AGs4fgrkAElkMrCIbW1kqmIIfoA3WzEOIlJoTy2pShllexAWbNoFLGuZWlprB6e35AigoxY4x-faCy5AosABEcg2AA8QTManUQQA2ACs0JMVX+b0B+ThAAVNtAUbDQQBmAAsKJ46OQSX+FKeXDRTxeZ3+nxcwR+fwxOSxoPBEChMNqoKR5IZ-0xwOQINxvgJQqlpPJnKpf1pPC47la7QmU14J0ksgu4muplMbWQ0Cg6CgAEIqPrDXZjbI7iaTO7zZbrXaHRYjRxrvJFLJWVEfgl3aatcgdfx7ac-U6Ay7gxYmRZQ+zkIlI7nzbGvEDloJ-MgALJwCF6CCCMAACwAYsAIRAsMzkD40qX-YQSGQoI69sxWCpMPCTDIBMIR5dxwaLK6Z+JEY5YlF3Ro0zYlxwVxo18EPJOhCIk5gV-Og-cd5gSavIofTJurNueyA7-uH24Ncfp2+75ei5vkS95fMYT6yEywGgWy36eLQU6nkOIAgYBwZvgATDB64QVuuyjiAWGfmBR4ISeN6EQmV74ZcACM2GPo4eEUfRxGweB8HIIhLFUUBZ4gAADAx35MS+NHiEJbE4Zx3FvkJaHXgeInPkySkcWsVBFtoJYZBWVY1vWADiEAgNAwAIO2sn8QAPHoFoQpA2DaMgcAgPwOYGnEAkzN5yC+f5PkJAAfFIfx2fyjlYM5cSudMyAAHSJaAMDkHoABKEZdH8AAUC7oTZ6UhVJjEqa+BVpUVmTsSYACUyBMH8ameMkQA)